# JavaScript closures and an unexpected - undefined - return

Tags: javascript, closures, undefined

while I'm trying to understand JS closures, i wrote this code :

```js
const outer = function() {
  let a = 10, c = 100;
  const inner = function() {
    let b = 20;
    console.log(a + b); // line 5 (30)
  };
  return inner;
};
let K = outer();
console.log(K()); // line 10 (undefined)
```

The console's output:

> 30 ( line 5)
>
> undefined ( line 10 )
>
> the console outputs the result ( 30 )

and it points to (line 5) of the code ( this seems reasonable for me )
after that ( and that's what I didn't understand) it returns undefined when it gets back to the last line of code ( line 10 )
Anyone can clarify this JS behavior?

Comment: `K` doesn't return anything. It just `console.log`s.  change `console.log(a + b);` to `return a+b;` inside `inner` and it will console as you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `K` is the result of executing `outer`, which in this case is the function `inner`.

When you execute `K` (which has been assigned the function defined as `inner` earlier), you get the console output of 30, which is `a + b`.

However, you also log the return value of `K`, and because your `inner` function doesn't have a return value, you get `undefined`.

Try modifying your code to have `inner` return a value and you'll see what I mean:

```js
const outer = function(){
    let a = 10, c = 100 ; 
    const inner = function(){
        let b = 20 ; 
        console.log( a + b ) ; 
        return a * b; // Without this return, the return value of inner is undefined.
    }
    return inner ; 
}
let K = outer(); 
console.log( K() ) ;
```

Comment: I get it now, a function without a "return" statement will return undefined, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Adamdjennaba when an answer answers you're question you can mark it as answered by clicking the grey checkmark in the top left corner of the answer